# bash scripting - wget or curl file with action based on the status 200 or not

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, wget, curl

I would like to write a script where I try to download a file with wget (or curl if is really not something that can be done with wget) and do 2 actions if the file exists and it's downloaded correctly or... something else if the file is not downloaded correctly or is not found/server timeout/whatever else from being downloaded correctly.

How this can be achieved? Wget | sed/grep something -> == "200".. or a compare based on filesize shown in the headers.. ? then the actions?

Comment: "Downloaded correctly" can be tricky -- see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271070/117549

Comment: You might want to add `-t 1` to ensure that when wget exits ok you will find the file under the expected filename, and not for example "file.1". See JeffSchaller's link.

Comment: @meuh good pick ;) however in my script i have a fixed `-O` option already in so it will always overwrite a specific file without adding the `.1 .2 .3` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs like `wget` and `curl` already exit with an error if the download fails. You can use a normal bash `if` without pipes:

```
if wget [...]
then
  echo 'Downloaded :-)'
else
  echo 'Error :-('
fi
```

Comment: This will cover any case? I mean `if wget...` will return true only if the file is fully downloaded without issues of any kind ? Fully downloaded file not just status 200, you know, to cover even the case my router reboots during the download! :)

Comment: That's how `wget` and any *Unix & Linux* program is expected to work. You can check documentation of the exit status of wget [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html): *0: No problems occurred.*

Comment: If your router reboots and the download is interrupted, wget will return an error.